# CosmosDB retrieve documents has keys sorted by name

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am storing a document in the cosmos DB and trying to retrieve it in the same key order as it was inserted. For example my data is:

```
{
'name':'James',
'age':22,
'company':'xyz',
}
```

But when I fetch it from the DB it comes in this order:

```
{
'age':22,
'company':'xyz',
'name':'James'
}
```

I am unable to understand why it is sorting the order. Is there any way to retain the order?

Comment: Just curious, what difference it would make?

Comment: I want to export it in a file. For that column order matters.

Comment: IMHO, you should not be doing that. It may happen that one record gets inserted like `{
'name':'James',
'age':22,
'company':'xyz',
}` while other record might get inserted like `{
'age':22, 'name':'James',
'company':'xyz',
}` and that would create problems in your export.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually I am inserting in a particular order only. So that's not an issue

Comment: Can you share your code for exporting?

Comment: I am exporting in an excel file. For now I am doing a workaround in pandas. df.to_excel(path, columns=col_ordered_list)

I am looking for some better way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the order in the query sql:

```
select c.name,c.age,c.company from c
```

BTW,it makes no difference when you process this json structure result.Key-Value has no order.

Comment: I have 70+ keys. Can't do like that.

Comment: @Anurag What file?Csv?

Comment: @Anurag I think you could control how they dumped into your file if you can't set all the columns.

Comment: I am exporting in an excel file. For now I am doing a workaround in pandas. df.to_excel(path, columns=col_ordered_list)

Comment: Is there any better way?